# Php : Curl With Headers Not Working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to set an headers in curl.But My curl is not working if i use headers.  Below is my code.

```
   $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------643932844140921187526840362", "Content-Length: 1927");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://domain.com/submit/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    $last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    return array($result,$last);
    curl_close($ch);
```

But if I remove below code, code works fine.

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------643932844140921187526840362", "Content-Length: 1927");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Is this the correct way to set an header?  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you try to construct the multipart/form-data payload yourself?

Comment: i just want to replicate and form submission

Comment: What goes wrong? Are you outputting `curl_error()` to see errors?

Comment: page keeps on loading...its not getting completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

`"Content-Length: 1927"`

with

`"Content-Length: " . strlen($fields_string)`

Comment: @vishnu-vishwa i used your code and got the same error, page didn't stop loading then changed the conten-length since it isn't 1927 and page loaded completely and content was posted succefully. Can help you, sorry.